# Code duplication where impliment extension method for IEnumerable and IQueryable on entity set

Tags: c#, linq

Since Entity Set does not support asqueryable, I have to do this.  How can I reduce the amount of redundant code between the two methods?

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereCreateWithin<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, DateTime? beginDayParam = null) where T : IHasCreateDate
{
    if (beginDayParam == null)
    {
        beginDayParam = DateTime.Today;
    }

    DateTime beginDay = beginDayParam.Value.Date; 
    DateTime startRange;
    DateTime endRange;

    switch (timeRange)
    {
        case DateManager.TimeRange.All:

            return query;

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ThisYear:

            startRange = new DateTime(beginDay.Year, 1, 1); // January 1, this year
            endRange = startRange.AddYears(1);

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date < endRange);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ThisMonth:

            startRange = new DateTime(beginDay.Year, beginDay.Month, 1);
            endRange = startRange.AddMonths(1).Date;

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date < endRange);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ThisWeek:

            startRange = BuilkHelper.DateHelper.StartOfWeek(beginDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
            endRange = startRange.AddDays(6);

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date < endRange);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ToDay:

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date == beginDay);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.Last30Day:
            startRange = beginDay.AddDays(-29);
            endRange = beginDay;

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date <= endRange);
    }
    return query;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> WhereCreateWithin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, DateTime? beginDayParam = null) where T : IHasCreateDate
{
    if (beginDayParam == null)
    {
        beginDayParam = DateTime.Today;
    }

    DateTime beginDay = beginDayParam.Value.Date;
    DateTime startRange;
    DateTime endRange;

    switch (timeRange)
    {
        case DateManager.TimeRange.All:

            return query;

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ThisYear:

            startRange = new DateTime(beginDay.Year, 1, 1); // January 1, this year
            endRange = startRange.AddYears(1);

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date < endRange);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ThisMonth:

            startRange = new DateTime(beginDay.Year, beginDay.Month, 1);
            endRange = startRange.AddMonths(1).Date;

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date < endRange);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ThisWeek:

            startRange = BuilkHelper.DateHelper.StartOfWeek(beginDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
            endRange = startRange.AddDays(6);

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date < endRange);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.ToDay:

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date == beginDay);

        case DateManager.TimeRange.Last30Day:
            startRange = beginDay.AddDays(-29);
            endRange = beginDay;

            return query.Where(p => p.create_date.Date >= startRange && p.create_date <= endRange);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the logic is exactly the same (i did not do a line by line comparision), one of the possible solutions whould be:

```
private static TCollection WhereCreateWithin<T, TCollection>(TCollection query,
             DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, 
             DateTime? beginDayParam,
             Func<TCollection, Func<T, bool>, TCollection> selector) 
    where T : IHasCreateDate
    where TCollection : IEnumerable<T>
{
    //insert your logic here
    //replace query.Where(x => ... ) call with selector(query, x => ... ) call
}

public static public static IQueryable<T> WhereCreateWithin<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, DateTime? beginDayParam = null) where T : IHasCreateDate
{
    return WhereCreateWithin<T, IQueryable<T>>(query, timeRange, beginDayParam, (q, f) => q.Where(x => f(x)))
}


public static public static IEnumerable<T> WhereCreateWithin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, DateTime? beginDayParam = null) where T : IHasCreateDate
{
    return WhereCreateWithin<T, IEnumerable<T>>(query, timeRange, beginDayParam, (q, f) => q.Where(f))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The IQueryable Where extension method takes an Expression whereas the IEnumerable Where extension method takes a normal delegate (Func). Any solution to consolidate the OPs code will have to take this into account. It is easy to convert an expression to a delegate by calling Compile on the expression (but hard the other way around) therefore I have based the below solution on the first principle.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereCreateWithin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, DateTime? beginDayParam = null) where T : IHasCreateDate
{
    return WhereCreateWithin<IEnumerable<T>, T>(query, timeRange, (q, ex) => q.Where(ex.Compile()), beginDayParam); 
}

public static IQueryable<T> WhereCreateWithin<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, DateTime? beginDayParam = null) where T : IHasCreateDate
{
    return WhereCreateWithin<IQueryable<T>, T>(query, timeRange, (q, ex) => q.Where(ex), beginDayParam); 
}

public static TColl WhereCreateWithin<TColl, T>(this TColl toBeFiltered, 
                                DateManager.TimeRange timeRange, 
                                Func<TColl, Expression<Func<T, bool>>, TColl> getFilteredCollection, 
                                DateTime? beginDayParam = null) where T : IHasCreateDate
                                                                where TColl : IEnumerable<T>
{
    if (beginDayParam == null)
    {
        beginDayParam = DateTime.Today;
    }

    DateTime beginDay = beginDayParam.Value.Date;

    var expressionDictionary = new Dictionary<DateManager.TimeRange, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>();
    expressionDictionary.Add(DateManager.TimeRange.ThisYear, p => p.create_date.Date >= new DateTime(beginDay.Year, 1, 1) && p.create_date < new DateTime(beginDay.Year, 1, 1).AddYears(1));
    expressionDictionary.Add(DateManager.TimeRange.ThisMonth, p => p.create_date.Date >= new DateTime(beginDay.Year, beginDay.Month, 1) && p.create_date < new DateTime(beginDay.Year, beginDay.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).Date);
    expressionDictionary.Add(DateManager.TimeRange.ThisWeek, p => p.create_date.Date >= BuilkHelper.DateHelper.StartOfWeek(beginDay, DayOfWeek.Monday) && p.create_date < BuilkHelper.DateHelper.StartOfWeek(beginDay, DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(6));
    expressionDictionary.Add(DateManager.TimeRange.ToDay, p => p.create_date.Date == beginDay);
    expressionDictionary.Add(DateManager.TimeRange.Last30Day, p => p.create_date.Date >= beginDay.AddDays(-29) && p.create_date <= beginDay);

    return expressionDictionary.ContainsKey(timeRange) ? getFilteredCollection(toBeFiltered, expressionDictionary[timeRange]) : toBeFiltered;

}
```